# Azure : Input port for endpoint

Tags: azure, deployment

My cloud service is composed of one Web role and one worker role (a dedicated cache). The web role hosts web service written on Web API. I have configured the web role's end point as an input end point type with public port set to 80. Private port is left empty.

When I run this service locally on Azure Emulator, the service seems to be listening to port 81 instead of 80. (I get the home page opening on the browser with url `http://127.0.0.1:81/`). Why does this happen?

When I deploy the service on Azure against a cloud service say "myservice", I want the service accessible as `http://myservice.cloudapp.net/` . How do I achieve this?

Comment: If I may suggest something - Azure WebSites (kinda) recently went out of beta, and we've had nothing but good experience switching our WebAPI projects from hosting as web roles to hosting as websites. The deployment cycle became shorter, the Azure emulator is no longer required, and deployment takes 10 seconds each time instead of 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run this service locally on Azure Emulator, the service seems
>   to be listening to port 81 instead of 80. (I get the home page opening
>   on the browser with url http:// 127.0.0.1:81/). Why does this happen?

The reason this is happening is because you have IIS running on port 80. To avoid port conflict, the compute emulator automatically assigns port 81. See the screenshot below from the output window in Visual Studio.

[image]

> When I deploy the service on Azure against a cloud service say
>   "myservice", I want the service accessible as
>   http://myservice.cloudapp.net/ . How do I achieve this?

You don't have to do anything special. Just make sure that port 80 is configured as an endpoint as shown in the screenshot below (which I believe you have already done)

[image]